# How can I rbind with Factors?

Tags: r, rbind

If I have two data.frames with the same column names, I can use rbind to make a single data frame.  However, if I have factors in the columns, I get an error like this:

```
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Is there a command I can use that will somehow merge the factors into one list?  I can convert to characters and back to factors, but is there a command that does this for me?

Comment: Can't test without a reproducible example, but `rbindlist()` from `data.table` package handles `factor` types with non-identical levels as well. You may want to try the devel version 1.9.5 - installation instructions [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

Comment: How can I tell what factors are the ones causing the problem?  How do I interpret the warnings?

Comment: can you `dput()` your data?

Comment: Let me shrink it down.  It's too big right now.

Comment: Found the issue.  I was binding an int and a factor.  Will revise the question to understand how to find this out.